# How to get a list of inputs from a view?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a list of products that each one needs the amounts to return and the reason for return. I cannot change the model referenced (as it determines many of the values) How do I get the list of all the inputs to pass to the controller?

I tried to use javascript to send the information through but I have no real idea what I'm doing connecting razor to javascript.

My View:

```
..@model Snow_System.Models.mvcProductOrderModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Take in Order Return";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1 class="page-header pageHeading" style="text-align:center;">Take in Returned Stock</h1>
<hr />

<div class="TopInfoContainer">
    <h2 class="SectionHeading">Order Information</h2>
    <div class="TopInfoLeft">
        <label for="ordID">  Order ID: </label> <span name="ordIDInfo"> @Model.ProductOrderID</span><br />
        <label for="ordDate">  Date placed:</label> <span name="ordDate">@Model.DateOfOrder</span>
    </div>
    <div class="TopInfoRight">
        <label for="ordLocation">Order Location:</label> <span name="ordLocation"> @Model.Client.HouseAddress</span><br />
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<h2 class="SectionHeading">Product list</h2>
<table class="table">
    <tr class="table-primary">
        <th>
            Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Type
        </th>
        <th>
            Quantity on Hand
        </th>
        <th>
            Amount Ordered
        </th>
        <th>
            Amount to Return
        </th>
        <th>
            Reason for Return
        </th>
        <th>
            Payback Amount
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.ProductOrderLines)
{
<tr class="table-dark" style="cursor:default;">
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product.ProductType)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product.QuantityOnHand)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QuantityOrdered)
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="number" class="form-control return-amount" max="@item.QuantityOrdered" min="0" value="0" onchange="CalcSubtotal(@item.ProductID, this, @item.Product.SellingPrice)" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Reason for return" class="form-control return-reason" />
    </td>
    <td id="@item.ProductID">
    </td>
</tr>
}
</table>

<div id="AuxilaryOptionsContainer">

</div>
<br />
<br />
<div onclick="document.getElementById('ReturnOrderModal').style.display='block'" class="OptionButton ContinueBtn btn btn-success" style="float:right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span> <br />Capture Return</div>
<div class="OptionButton BackBtn btn btn-danger" style="position: relative; bottom: 0; left: 0; "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span><br />Cancel</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#emailSuppliers .btn").click(function () {
            $(this).button('toggle');
        });
    });

    function CalcSubtotal(id, input, price) {
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "R" + input.value * price + ".00";
    }
</script>

<div id="ReturnOrderModal" class="modal animate-opacity">
    <div class="modal-content modal-background">
        <header class="">
            <h2>Confirm Return</h2>
        </header>
        <hr style="margin:0;" />
        <div style="text-align:center; font-size:500%"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style="margin-top:3%;"></span></div>
        <div class="">
            <p>Are you sure you want to return this order?</p>
        </div>
        <hr style="margin:0;" />
        <footer class="" style="">
            <div onclick="document.getElementById('ReturnOrderModal').style.display='none'" class="btn btn-outline-danger" style="width:25%; margin:2%; margin-top:2%;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span><br />No</div>
            <div class="btn btn-outline-success" style="width:25%; margin:2%; margin-top:2%;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span><br />Yes</div>
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Models
Product order line:

```
namespace Snow_System.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class mvcProductOrderLineModel
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public mvcProductOrderLineModel()
        {
            this.ProductOrderReturnLines = new HashSet<mvcProductOrderReturnLineModel>();
        }

        public double Selling_Price { get; set; }
        public int QuantityOrdered { get; set; }
        public int QuantityDelivered { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public int ProductOrderID { get; set; }

        public virtual mvcProductModel Product { get; set; }
        public virtual mvcProductOrderModel ProductOrder { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<mvcProductOrderReturnLineModel> ProductOrderReturnLines { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Product order

```
namespace Snow_System.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class mvcProductOrderModel
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public mvcProductOrderModel()
        {
            this.ProductOrderLines = new HashSet<mvcProductOrderLineModel>();
        }

        public int ProductOrderID { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DateOfOrder { get; set; }
        public int ProductOrderStatusID { get; set; }
        public int Client_ID { get; set; }

        public virtual mvcClientModel Client { get; set; }
        public virtual mvcProductOrderStatuModel ProductOrderStatu { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<mvcProductOrderLineModel> ProductOrderLines { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Product order returns

```
namespace Snow_System.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class mvcProductOrderReturnLineModel
    {
        public int ProductOrderID { get; set; }
        public int ProductOrderReturnID { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public string ReasonForReturn { get; set; }
        public int ProductID { get; set; }

        public virtual mvcProductOrderLineModel ProductOrderLine { get; set; }
        public virtual mvcProductOrderReturnModel ProductOrderReturn { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I need inputs and the productID (Model.Product.ID) in the table to be passed to the controller.

Comment: Make an ajax call to the controller. https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/asp-net-core-razor-pages-how-to-implement-ajax-requests/

Comment: If you want the details as list in controller then have common class , or a controlled dynamic id to your html controls, then just loop through your table and get the data based on the common class or id and append it to an array.Each row data will be an object in the array and finally send that array of objects to controller using ajax. The controller parameter should match with your object definition

Answer (score 0):

Start by doing a for loop

```
@for (int i =0;i<Model.ProductOrderLines.Count;i++)
```

Then use the index to display and textbox

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.ProductOrderLines[i].Product.Name)

@Html.TextboxFor(modelItem => Model.ProductOrderLines[i].QuantityOrdered)
```

When you receive the data back to the controller, it'll know under which index all the data are for (see for yourself by doing a view source). You can also receive a FormCollection collection and call TryUpdateModel to update the model.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Html.HiddenFor as solution of your purpose. Here is the steps to resolved your problem. You may take a look as your solution.

### Model Class (Product Model And ProductItem)

```
public class ProductItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int QuantityOnHand { get; set; }
    public int AmountOrdered { get; set; }
    public int AmountToReturn { get; set; }
    public string ReasonForReturn { get; set; }
    public int PaybackAmount { get; set; }
}

public class ProductModel
{
    public ProductModel()
    {
        ProductItems = new List<ProductItem>();
    }

    public List<ProductItem> ProductItems { get; set; }
}
```

### Controller (ProductController)

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Product()
    {
        ProductModel productModel = GetProductModels();

        return View(productModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Product(ProductModel productModel)
    {
        int productCount = productModel.ProductItems.Count;

        return View(productModel);
    }


    private ProductModel GetProductModels()
    {
        ProductModel productModel = new ProductModel();

        productModel.ProductItems.Add(new ProductItem() { Name = "Product_1", Type = "A", QuantityOnHand = 50, AmountOrdered = 20, AmountToReturn = 5, PaybackAmount = 110, ReasonForReturn = "Looking for something else!"});
        productModel.ProductItems.Add(new ProductItem() { Name = "Product_2", Type = "B", QuantityOnHand = 50, AmountOrdered = 20, AmountToReturn = 5, PaybackAmount = 110, ReasonForReturn = "Looking for something else!" });
        productModel.ProductItems.Add(new ProductItem() { Name = "Product_3", Type = "C", QuantityOnHand = 50, AmountOrdered = 20, AmountToReturn = 5, PaybackAmount = 110, ReasonForReturn = "Looking for something else!" });
        productModel.ProductItems.Add(new ProductItem() { Name = "Product_4", Type = "D", QuantityOnHand = 50, AmountOrdered = 20, AmountToReturn = 5, PaybackAmount = 110, ReasonForReturn = "Looking for something else!" });

        return productModel;
    }`enter code here`
}
```

### View (Product.cshtml)

you need add hidden html helper inside the for loop. Your contain should be under BeginForm helper. Use a button and type should be Summit. After clicking on the button, you will see the all list at controller post action.

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.ProductItems.Count; i++)

```
                        @Html.DisplayFor(p => p.ProductItems[i].Name, new { @id = "ItemName_" + i })
                        @Html.HiddenFor(p => p.ProductItems[i].Name, new { @id = "ItemName_" + i })
                    </td>
```

You can add more td as per your need. Here is just one

Comment: holding all these data into hidden field is not a good practice, instead you should have it in an array of object and pass it to controller using ajax

Comment: This was his requirement that’s why I told to use hidden with only required fields. Off course there are some other way to do this. You may share one of them